# Accessing external device libraries from Matlab and MEX file

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, mex

I've been trying for to exchange data with a device using Matlab R2016a with no success. I tried both running developers' Matlab example and this:

```
loadlibrary('myDevice.dll','myDevice.h')
```

but both result in the same error:

```
Error using loadlibrary
Failed to preprocess the input file.
Output from preprocessor is: myDevice.h
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xtgmath.h(214) : warning C4602: #pragma pop_macro : 'new' no previous #pragma push_macro for this identifier
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\eh.h(27) : fatal error C1189: #error :  "eh.h is only for C++!"
```

From looking at other threads in this forum (for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526557/write-c-dll-for-matlab)), my understanding is that some C++ resource is being used in an otherwise C code. Unfortunately, I have no knowledge whatsoever of either C or C++, so I am unable to confirm this (let alone fix it).
So, the first question is: did the device developers make some stupid mistake in writing the relevant code (and there is actually a mismatching of C and C++ codes) or am I missing something very obvious, here?

Another thread suggested wrapping everything in a MEX file. So I ran a C++ example from the device developers in Visual Studio 2013 to make sure this example was working. It ran without problems. Then I proceeded to strip down the C++ example to try and make a very simple MEX to test the device with.

This is what was left in my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <map>

#include "myDevice.h"
#include "mex.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "myDevice.lib")

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int state = EngineConnect();
    return;
}
```

The first list of 'includes' is straight from their example, as I am not quite sure of what is actually needed here.

Trying to generate the MEX with:

```
mex -lmyDevice.lib EngineConnect.cpp
```

resulted in this error:

```
Error using mex
   Creating library EngineConnect.lib and object EngineConnect.exp
EngineConnect.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EngineConnect referenced in function
"void __cdecl mexFunction(void)" (?mexFunction@@YAXXZ)
EngineConnect.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I am sure the .lib file is in the correct position (renaming it results in a 'file not found' error) and the function name is correct, as renaming the  EngineConnect function in the myDevice.h file results in:

```
Error using mex
EngineConnect.cpp
C:\Code\Tests\EngineConnect.cpp(17) : error C3861: 'EngineConnect': identifier not found
```

so I am not understanding what the unresolved externals error is referring to, or how to fix it.

While I do have a long history with Matlab, I've basically never used MEX files before, so, once more, I may be overlooking something basic. Going over the documentation did not help, though. Also, first post here, I hope I was clear enough with my question. In case it's useful, I am working with Windows 7, SP1, 64bit.

**EDIT.** For reading simplicity, Amro's changes have been introduced in this post. However, the resulting error is unchanged.

Comment: try compiling the mex-file with: `mex -largeArrayDims EngineConnect.cpp -L"C:\Code\Tests" -ledk -lmyDevice`. Also dont forget to add `#include "mex.h"` which is needed for any mex-file

Comment: @ amro Sorry, the mex.h was included in the script. I somehow lost that line in the post. Also, my MEX generation should have been `mex -lmyDevice.lib EngineConnect.cpp` (I was trying to remove references to actual device). I get the same error even after your suggestion, though.

Comment: Did you try running the command as I specified? The order sometimes matter. The general structure is `mex -largeArrayDims -I"C:\path\to\include" file.cpp -L"C:\path\to\libs" -lmylib1 -lmylib2` assuming you have the .h, .lib, and .dll files in the expected locations (note that there is no .lib suffix in the -lmylib syntax)

Comment: Yep, I tested your code, along with several other permutations of parameter order. Always get the same unresolved externals error. I'm pretty sure the compiler is finding the files it needs, as if I rename them, I get a 'file not found' error.

Comment: Is the device library available publicly? It would help if we have access to it to try ourselves... BTW the `mexFunction` signature in your example is wrong, you're missing the arguments `plhs` and `prhs` and their lengths.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know you had to pass arguments even in the case the function did not require any. Anyway, even changing `void mexFunction()` with `void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])` results in the same unresolved externals error. And unfortunately no, device libraries are not publicly available.

Comment: well then you have to describe more thoroughly the files you have, where they are on the file system, what symbols are exported from this library, what functions are defined in header files, etc... Also state clearly the commands you're using to compile and the full error messages if any. Otherwise it's just guesswork.